# fetch same name for two different fields in mysql

Tags: mysql

This is my slelect query i want to fetch same field name two times processNm and 
in nxtProcess i want to fetch name from processmaster but i am not getting any output

in my process table i have two same field processMasterId,nextProcessId in this fields same id inserted from processmaster table i want fetch his name. but i cant get any output..

```
SELECT designMaster.designMasterId,dNo,dWet,nextProcess,itemnm,SUM(moldNo) AS moldNo
                 ,mold,status,processNm AS preProcess,processNm AS nxtProcess,nextProcessId
     FROM   designMaster,item,moldmaster,processmaster,process
     WHERE  item.itemId = designMaster.itemId
     AND   process.processMasterId = process.nextProcessId
     AND   process.designMasterId = designMaster.designMasterId
     AND  moldmaster.designMasterId = designMaster.designMasterId
     AND  processmaster.processMasterId = designMaster.nextProcess
    GROUP BY designMaster.designMasterId
    ORDER BY designMaster.designMasterId
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query is not valid.  You're using GROUP BY improperly.  All columns other than your SUM() need to be part of the group.

```
create table designMaster (
    designMasterId number,
    nextProcess number,
    itemId number,
    dNo number
);

create table item (
    itemId number,
    itemnm number
);

create table moldmaster (
    designMasterId number,
    moldNo number,
    mold number    
);

create table process (
    processId number,
    processMasterId number,
    processDate date,
    workerId number,
    designMasterId number,
    desWet number,
    dWet number,
    rDate date,
    reciveWet number,
    rejWet number,
    nextProcessId number,
    status number
);

create table processmaster (
    processMasterId number,
    processNm number,
    sequence number
);

SELECT designMaster.designMasterId,dNo,dWet,nextProcess,itemnm,SUM(moldNo) AS moldNo
        ,mold,status,processNm AS preProcess,processNm AS nxtProcess,nextProcessId
 FROM   designMaster,item,moldmaster,processmaster,process
 WHERE  item.itemId = designMaster.itemId
 AND   process.processMasterId = process.nextProcessId
 AND   process.designMasterId = designMaster.designMasterId
 AND  moldmaster.designMasterId = designMaster.designMasterId
 AND  processmaster.processMasterId = designMaster.nextProcess
GROUP BY designMaster.designMasterId,dNo,dWet,nextProcess,itemnm,mold,status,processNm,nextProcessId
ORDER BY designMaster.designMasterId;
```

Comment: me already do it. it's give me empty result set.. like this :- processmaster.processNm  AS preProcess,processmaster.processNm AS nxtProcess @Mark Leiber..

Comment: We need more information about the tables and the data.  Can you provide a sample record that you expect to see returned?

Comment: Take a single record that you expect to be returned and provide the data related to that record that is in each of the tables in your FROM clause (all five tables).

Comment: u want to see field name also?

Comment: this id my process table fields processId,processMasterId,processDate,workerId,designMasterId,desWet,rDate,reciveWet,rejWet,nextProcessId,status

Comment: this is myprocessmaster table fields processMasterId,processNm,sequence... i want to fetch processNm as preprocess and as a nextporcess also..

Comment: What table has dWet, dNo, moldNo, and mold?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73423/discussion-between-mark-leiber-and-user1866385).

Comment: Click the link above (http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73423/discussion-between-mark-leiber-and-user1866385)